# How to generate hashCode() and equals() for a package in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-mars

I have various class in this package. Is it possible to generate `hashCode()` and `equals()` for all classes in this package at once?

Comment: You want to do what? Package is just a way of storing files in a manageable way.

Comment: only objects are having  these methods and package is not an object.

Comment: Eclipse can generate hashCode() and equals() for classes...

Comment: hashCode() - for object is unique id, equals() is way for comparison

Comment: I have various class in this package. Is it possible to generate hashCode() and equals() for all class in this package at once?

Comment: @MaxUsanin There's nothing unique about a hashcode.

Comment: There are decisions to be made when generating `hashCode()` and `equals()` - namely which fields to use in the comparison. It's very difficult to do this at the package level which is why the function is not available

Comment: @LanceJava I want to use all fields in hashCode() and equals().

Answer (score 3):

If you need to auto generate `hashCode()` and `equals()` in eclipse for each class in certain package

Open every java class >>> right click >> sourse >>> generate `hashCode()` and `equals()`

Maybe if the number of classes too big then you can create java task to open every file and append the hashcode() and equals()

Comment: You have got this right. I have various class in this package. Is it possible to generate hashCode() and equals() for all class in this package at once?

Comment: So I have to generate hashCode() and equals() each class individually

Comment: it will be couple strings ... or a implementation?

Comment: As I know you can not, but maybe if the number of classes too big then you can create java task to open every file and append the hashcode()  and equals()

Answer (score 0):

can you imagine when you have implementation of "equal()" for classes and you will choose for package "generate please method equal()" what must decide eclipse ? I think if you want to generate a methods automatically for package of classes -  you can make own code..

Answer (score 0):

Not Specific for package but apache common's HashCodebuilder and EqualsBuilder can help you to implement it in correct way

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

Currently Eclipse does not support this feature. Enhancement [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=474761) is raised for this.